# How to submit a Pardot form using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, pardot, httppost

I am confused a little bite, why pardot is not allowing such ajax requests ? aren't they more user friendly features ?

I added a form handler and tried to use it of course & it works when I keep the default submission.

When I try to do so whith XMLHttpRequest I get this beautiful error :

```
index.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://go.pardot.com/my-long-url-here' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is my code :

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", 'http://go.pardot.com/l/903091/2021-02-05/4cqj', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { // Call a function when the state changes.
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            // Request finished. Do processing here.
        } else {
            alert("error of course")
        }
    }
    xhr.send("email=taoufiq@gmail.com");
    // xhr.send(new Int8Array());
    // xhr.send(document);
```

The form has just a simple email!

Is there a way to make this work with AJAX ? any tutorial on this, becuase I can't find a clear documentation on this matter.

Any help would be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per this article
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317110&type=1

Pardot doesn't currently support CORS or JSONP for form handlers. It is possible to simulate a JSONP response by setting the Success and Error URLs for the form handler to be JavaScript URLs that execute Success and Error callbacks, respectively.

Comment: I have managed to pass through an imtermediate servers, call from JS to that servers( ajava, php, whatever ) and that backend is somehow able to connect to pardot via https request easily, .. so I did this instead of using JSONP, what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Pardot does not support CORS or JSONP. We need to the mode to "no-cors" inside the request.

```
const formData = new FormData(form);
const data = {
    "Email" : formData.get('Email'),
    "FirstName": formData.get('FirstName'),
    "LastName" : formData.get('LastName'),
    "Company" : formData.get('Company'),
}
const response = await fetch("https://pardot.insightinhealth.com/l/981732/2023-02-16/hhh3y", {
    // Set the FormData instance as the request body
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: new URLSearchParams(data),
    headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;"
    }
  });
```